# Magento EE - Can not install patch EE-1.14.3.9-1.14.3.10-2018-09-17-05-45-48.diff

Tags: magento-enterprise, patches, installation, magento-1.14.3.3, magento-1.14.3.10

I tried to install

> EE-1.14.3.9-1.14.3.10-2018-09-17-05-45-48.diff patch

using command

```
patch -p1 -f  EE-1.14.3.9-1.14.3.10-2018-09-17-05-45-48.diff
```

I also tried command

```
patch -p1 -f  EE-1.14.3.9-1.14.3.10-2018-09-17-05-45-48.diff
```

I tried both ways, however It's stuck once I fire the command. I don't get any kind of errors in log. Magento also works smoothly but installation cannot proceed.

[image]

Comment: Try this **patch <  EE-1.14.3.9-1.14.3.10-2018-09-17-05-45-48.diff**

Comment: Glad it worked :)